# Document Object Model element

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I got this error

> Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.

when I want to create a header for my web page and the problem that I'm following a YouTube video to learn react, and I got this issues and in the YouTube video he didn't have the same problem as me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
    body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif}
    .w3-bar,h1,button {font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif}
    .fa-anchor,.fa-coffee {font-size:200px}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div className="Home"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">
                class Header extends React.Component {
                render(){
                    return(
                        <div className="w3-top">
      <div className="w3-bar w3-red w3-card w3-left-align w3-large">
        <a className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right w3-padding-large w3-hover-white w3-large w3-red" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i className="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
        <a href="#" className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-white">Home</a>
        <a href="#" className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#" className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#" className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#" className="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-padding-large w3-hover-white">Link 4</a>
      </div>
      </div>
                    )
    
    
                }
            }
    
    
    
    
            class Home extends React.Component {
                render(){
                    return(
                        <header />
                    )
    
    
                }
            }
            ReactDOM.render(<Home/>,document.getElementById("app"))
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You are getting an element by ID of `app` yet you don't have such element with such ID. You have an element with ID of `Home` instead. So change that.

Comment: still the same probleme  sir even i change it

Comment: no you have not. the `Home` is a class. you need to change it to `id=app`

Answer (score 0):

In `reactDOM.render()` you are rendering your app to `document.getElementById("app")` which does not exist on your page. You need to add an element with the id of app to your page so the react app can render to a valid element.

So somewhere in the body of your page add the element `<div id="app"></div>`

or if you are meaning to render your app to the `Home` element you need to change the function to say something like:

`ReactDOM.render(<Home/>,document.querySelector(".Home"))`.

and then change your element to say something like:

`<div class="Home"></div>`

You only need to use className to specify a class inside of a react element. So `<div className="Home"></div>` is not valid html it should be `<div class="Home"></div>`. But inside a react element you would use `<div className="your-class"></div>`.

Comment: Should not use `class` for selectors. Possible - but shouldn’t. Use `id` instead.

Comment: ah thank you everything work great now but i have a question why if i change document.getElementById with document.getElementsByClassName it doesn't work and still the same error display to me

Comment: @Lith really its just semantics. It's better practice to use an id but it really doesn't matter as long as you are selecting a valid element.

Comment: @MiralKh document.getElementByClassname returns an array of all the elements with that class https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName and not just one specific element.

Comment: ah okay so what if i want to work with class what should i do ?

Comment: @MiralKh You can use querySelector so something like `document.querySelector('.your-class')` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector this will select the first instance of whatever you put in there. But if you have multiple instances of the class then you will have to grab the array and select which one you want. Also you don't need to post the answer I gave  you that's not really how this site is supposed to work. Just click the checkmark next to this answer to signify its the correct answer.